# Kotlin: Dynamically choose companion object function

Tags: kotlin, enums, companion-object

My Enum class and companion object are as follows:

```
enum class Temperature(val names: List<String>) {
    Celsius(listOf("degree Celsius", "degrees Celsius", "celsius", "dc", "c")),
    Kelvin(listOf("Kelvin", "Kelvins", "k")),
    Fahrenheit(listOf("degree Fahrenheit", "degrees Fahrenheit", "fahrenheit", "df", "f"));

    companion object Conversion {
        fun CelsiusToKelvin(c: Double) = c + 273.15
        fun CelsiusToFahrenheit(c: Double) = (c * 9 / 5) + 32
        fun FahrenheitToKelvin(f: Double) = (f + 459.67) * 5 / 9
        fun FahrenheitToCelsius(f: Double) = (f - 32) * 5 / 9
        fun KelvinToCelsius(K: Double) = K - 273.15
        fun KelvinToFahrenheit(K: Double) = K * 9 / 5 - 459.67
    }
}
```

I get input temperature in a scale which I need to convert to a different output scale. Is there a way to dynamically call the companion object functions based on the input and output scales?

For example:

```
var convert = "CelsiusToKelvin"
val value = 36.9
val myFunc = Temperature.getFunction(convert)
val myOutput = myFunc(value)
```

This should invoke the `Temperature.CelsiusToKelvin` function.

I know that I can check the input using `if` or `when` statements and manually invoke the function I want. But is it possible without doing this?

---

Edit 1:

I solved it using when by changing the function:

```
companion object Conversion {
        fun convert(a:String,b:String,c:Double) = when {
            a == "Celsius" && b == "Kelvin" -> c + 273.15
            a == "Celsius" && b == "Fahrenheit" -> (c * 9 / 5) + 32
            a == "Fahrenheit" && b == "Kelvin" -> (c + 459.67) * 5 / 9
            a == "Fahrenheit" && b == "Celsius" -> (c - 32) * 5 / 9
            a == "Kelvin" && b == "Celsius" -> c - 273.15
            a == "Kelvin" && b == "Fahrenheit" -> c * 9 / 5 - 459.67
            else -> 0.0
        }
    }
```

But I want to know if what I originally wanted to do was possible

Comment: Well, surely you can call a function chosen by a string name using e.g. reflection. But as for me, this approach looks cumbersome and suboptimal. I would choose an different one, involving a sealed class Temperature with a set of known converters (`toCelcius`, `toFahrenheit` and `toKelvin`) and thus abstracted from the source temperature type

Answer (score 2):

I think a better approach, if you must use `String`s, is to dynamically determine the *constant*, and have each constant provide the necessary conversion functions. For example:

```kotlin
// Note: Didn't include your "names" property
enum class Temperature {
    Celsius {
        override fun toKelvin(value: Double) = value + 273.15
        override fun toFahrenheit(value: Double) = (value * 9.0 / 5.0) + 32.0
    },
    Kelvin {
        override fun toCelsius(value: Double) = value - 273.15
        override fun toFahrenheit(value: Double) = value * 9.0 / 5.0 - 459.67
    },
    Fahrenheit {
        override fun toCelsius(value: Double) = (value - 32.0) * 5.0 / 9.0
        override fun toKelvin(value: Double) = (value + 459.67) * 5.0 / 9.0
    };

    open fun toCelsius(value: Double) = value
    open fun toKelvin(value: Double) = value
    open fun toFahrenheit(value: Double) = value

    fun convert(value: Double, target: Temperature) = when (target) {
        Celsius -> toCelsius(value)
        Kelvin -> toKelvin(value)
        Fahrenheit -> toFahrenheit(value)
    }

    companion object {

        fun convert(source: String, target: String, value: Double) =
            valueOf(source).convert(value, valueOf(target))
    }
}
```

The `valueOf` method, which is added implicitly by the compiler, will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if the string does not match the name of an enum constant *exactly*. Your code has a similar requirement except you return `0` if there's no match. I personally prefer the exception.